# Tkinter rectangle itemconfig fill update does not work every time

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm having a strange behavior with tkinter, canvas and itemconfig.

I have a small window, with a canvas that is filled with rectangles, each rectangle shows a color of a palette. I've setup an event for left & right mouse buttons, LMB selects a color, RMB swaps the clicked color with the selected one. The bind event is working fine, since other operations being done during this process happen (actual palette colors being swapped).

The thing is that upon first LMB & RMB click, the rectangles "fill" does not get updated (or at least there is no refresh on screen), but upon 2nd RMB click, the color change is reflected (but the color is swapped twice).

The code that updates the rectangles is:

```
app.paletteCanvas.itemconfig(app.paletteColorBoxes[newColor], fill=transformColor(app,app.drawColor))
app.paletteCanvas.itemconfig(app.paletteColorBoxes[app.drawColor], fill=transformColor(app,newColor))
```

app is the main application, paletteCanvas is the canvas which is packed in a "palette window", in app.paletteColorBoxes I keep the index of the rectangle to change, newColor and app.drawColor are the original color and color to swap, and finally transformColor just transgorms a (R,G,B) thing into a  #RRGGBB string for itemconfig to understand.

So, everything seems to work fine, except that upon first call to the routine the refresh is not done, but upon 2nd call the refresh is done.

I tried all sorts of .update() and .update_idletasks() but no luck.

To fully test this behavior you can check the full application at:

https://github.com/zayamatias/retrotool

The misbehaving function is in retrofunctions.py / swapColor

You need to open an image, click on some color and select "Tile Viewer/ Editor", after the tool is done (maybe it can fail, still WIP) you will see the palette window.

Thanks!

BTW I'm on Python 3.6.3 if that helps.

Comment: Please don't post a link to your full application. Nobody is going to want to wade through hundreds or thousands of lines of code. Instead, create a small [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally the issue was not with tkinter but with a mix up in teh values passed to the itemconfig method...my bad!